# How to remove square brackets and '' from string?

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time

headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get('https://www.hltv.org/stats/teams/7969/Nemiga?startDate=2019-01-01&endDate=2019-12-31')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'columns'})
results2 = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'large-strong'})

first_round = []
for result in results2:
    KDratio = result.contents
```

Output is ['1.04'].. is there a way I can get just 1.04 as the output?

Thanks

Comment: why you not using indexing in the list that you get?

Comment: So your output is a list containing a single string?

Comment: You  might want to re-read the part about lists in your Python tutorial.

Comment: if you want to take string from string try using regex (`re` library)

Comment: A quickfix would be using the str.replace function https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=replace#str.replace

Comment: You can use output.replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("'","")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your output is `out = "['1.04']"` you have (at least) two options.

1. String Operation

```py
out = "['1.04']"
num = float(out.strip("[']"))  # 1.04
```

2. String Parsing

```py
import ast

out = "['1.04']"
num = float(ast.literal_eval(out)[0])  # 1.04
```

Answer (score 2):

[`.contents`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html#contents-and-children) is a *list* containing all children. That's not what you want. You want the simple text content of the tag, for which you should use [`.string`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html#string).